# Is there a way to force libFTDI to make the python packages according to python2.7 instead of python3?

Tags: python, linux, cmake, ftdi

I need to use libFTDI (www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/download/libftdi1-1.2.tar.bz2)
for a project that I'm working on. All my current modules have been written in python2 and so i want libFTDI to work with python2 too, but the installation process automatically selects python3.5. Cmake is used to build the project. I can't seem to get it to work and apparently no one else has faced this problem before.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Within the documentation there is no hint that python3.5 is required. What's happen in case python3.5 is not available/installed?

Comment: @Th.Thielemann, i'm not sure what i did was stupid or not, but i renamed all directories of python versions apart from 2.7 to something else. The installation failed!

Comment: I do not have all prerequisites installed but python 2.7 and python was found.

Output:
`-- Could NOT find SWIG (missing:  SWIG_EXECUTABLE SWIG_DIR)
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (found version "2.7.10")
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found version "2.7.10")
-- Not building python bindings
-- Could NOT find Confuse (missing:  CONFUSE_LIBRARY CONFUSE_INCLUDE_DIR)`

Answer (score 1):

It worked after i uninstalled all versions of python3 and the python3-dev package.